# how can I tell - using terminal - how often the package manager checks for updates?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, server, package-management

I know on a desktop this can be checked easily,but I am using Ubuntu 14.04 server and need to be able to check the package managers update settings from the command line, how can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the value of `APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists` (Do `apt-get update` automatically every n-days, 0=disable):

```
grep APT::Periodic::Update-Package-Lists /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic
```

- 1: Every day
- 7: Every week

Comment: thanks!, I see the value in the `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10periodic` file as well as `APT::Periodic::Download-Upgradeable-Packages "0";`.

Answer (score 0):

Use cron. It lets you schedule tasks.
Run `crontab -e.`

On the file add lines

# Automatic package upgrades

```
0 0 * * 0 root (apt-get update && apt-get -y -d upgrade)
```

It will update the system  every Sunday morning at 12am.You can edit the numberto your needs.
The numbers here indicate minutes, hours, days,etc.
[Tech republic](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/automatically-update-your-ubuntu-system-with-cron-apt/) 
[Cron descirption](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl8_cron.htm)